# How to add local gem dependency to custom Logstash plugin?

Tags: logstash

I have a ruby gem file that is the actual Logstash plugin and I have another gem that the Logstash plugin gem requires. How do I get the gem into my Logstash so when I do

```
require "gem_name"
```

it doesn't say "can't find gem_name"?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
path/to/logstash/logstash-plugin install --no-verify --local localxxx.gem
```

Make sure your gem file (localxxx.gem) is within your logstash directory.

Answer (score 0):

As always, include your local gem as a dependency in your plugin.
Then, before installing your plugin, install the local dependency in Logstash like this:

```
/path/to/logstash/logstash-plugin install --no-verify /path/to/local/gem
```

And then install your plugin

```
/path/to/logstash/logstash-plugin install /path/to/local/plugin
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a line with the dependency to your **gemspec** (in your plugin folder named *plugin-name.gemspec*). E.g. if your plugin requires rest-client:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "rest-client", '>= 1.8.0'
```

You can find an example for a valid gemspec file with dependencies [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_filter_plugin.html#_add_a_literal_gemspec_literal_file_3). Take a look at the plugin of your choice on [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client/versions/2.0.0) to find valid version declarations.

Once you have all dependencies declared run `bundle install`, build your gem with `gem build your-plugin-name.gemspec`. Then install and test it: `bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-mypluginname.gem`.

I strongly recommend [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to avoid ruby version issues. You might also want to consider to stick to [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_filter_plugin.html) that makes it a lot easier. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: The question is "how to add a *local* gem dependency", not a regular, published gem dependency.